# Exponential of Lie Groups.

Tags: differential-geometry

When the exponential map  defined  a bijection between the group G and their Lie algebra? The only example  I know is the Heisenberg group.

Comment: Is it too late for a Breaking Bad reference?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes it is.

Answer (score 6):

The exponential map is a bijection implies that $G$ is contractible since the Lie algebra is a vector space, Let ${\cal G}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$, write ${\cal G}=V\oplus R$ where $R$ is the radical and $V$ is semi-simple, consider the subgroup $V_G$ of $G$ associated to $V$, the restriction of $exp$ to the Lie algebra of $V_G$ is injective if and only if $V_G$ is trivial, thus $V$ is trivial and $G$is solvable and simply connected. The converse is also true.

To show that $V$ is trivial, consider the restriction of $exp$ to the Lie algebra $D$ of the compact component $C$ of $V_G$ in its Iwasawa decomposition, this restriction is injective implies that $D$ is zero since for a compact Lie group, the exponential is surjective and if it is injective it is an homeomorphism and a vector space is compact if its dimension is zero. This shows that $C$ is trivial and henceforth $V$ is trivial since it is not solvable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

There is a really cool example that I love, given in a paper by [Arsigny, et al.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bf4c/1819546ec255d3997c8f5f9674282370e6eb.pdf) which shows that the symmetric positive definite matrices can be given a Lie group structure, and this is one such example where the exponential map is a bijection from the Lie group to its Lie algebra.  Let $SPD(n)$ be the manifold of symmetric positive definite matrices.  This can be realized as a manifold both as an open subset of the symmetric matrices $Symm(n)$, and also as a homogeneous space $SPD(n) \approx GL_n(\mathbb{R})/O(n)$ under the action $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times SPD(n) \to SPD(n)$ given by $(A, P) \to APA^T$.  Using the spectral theorem we can diagonalize any $P \in SPD(n)$ as $P = QDQ^T$ with $D$ diagonal with positive elements and $Q \in O(n)$.  Furthermore, the tangent space $T_PSPD(n) \cong Symm(n)$ at each point, hence the tangent vectors are symmetric matrices.  The matrix exponential map $\exp:Symm(n) \to SPD(n)$ given by the Taylor series has the convenient computational property that

$$
\exp(P) \;\; =\;\; Q\exp(D) Q^T
$$

and similarly the logarithm map $\log:SPD(n) \to Symm(n)$ defined by the usual Taylor expansion is defined for all matrices in $SPD(n)$ and serves as an inverse for $\exp$.

Now, the part that Arsigny and his collaborators introduced in their paper is how to turn $SPD(n)$ into a Lie group.  This can be done by introducing the binary operation $\odot: SPD(n) \times SPD(n) \to SPD(n)$ given by

$$
A\odot B \;\; =\;\; \exp(\log(A) + \log(B)).
$$

One can easily show that this operation is smooth and satisfies all of the conditions to turn $(SPD(n), \odot)$ into a Lie group.  What's also exciting too is that in the paper, the authors introduce a scalar multiplication that turns $SPD(n)$ into a vector space.

**Update 9/15/2019**

I wanted to update this example with a couple more features that will make this analysis a little more complete.

- Notice that the Lie group product turns $SPD(n)$ into a commutative Lie group.  This implies that the Lie algebra $Symm(n)$ is commutative, and rightfully so the bracket $[\cdot, \cdot]: Symm(n) \times Symm(n) \to Symm(n)$ is trivial.  This fact is correctly reflected in the Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff formula:

$$
\log\left (\exp(A) \odot \exp(B)\right ) \;\; =\;\; A+B.
$$

- Observe now that the Lie group structure $(SPD(n), \odot)$ is really just the pushforward of vector addition on $Symm(n)$ via $\exp$, and this is afforded to us by the fact that $\exp$ is a global diffeomorphism.  We can extend this to a vector space structure on $SPD(n)$ by also pushing forward the scalar multiplication.  Arsigny et al. defined the operation $\circledast:\mathbb{R} \times SPD(n) \to SPD(n)$ given by
  $$
  \lambda\circledast P \;\; =\;\; \exp \left (\lambda \log(P)\right ).
  $$

One can show that $\circledast$ satisfies the distributive properties of scalar multiplication and in fact serves as a scalar multiplication on $SPD(n)$.

**Update 2/4/2023**

Another great example in this same vein was [published recently](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/sta4.494?saml_referrer) that shows that correlation values themselves possess Lie group structure and this is another case where the group is isomorphic to the Lie algebra.  [Research](http://oam.ele-math.com/13-46/A-Riemannian-structure-for-correlation-matrices) has shown that correlation matrices have a quotient manifold structure

$$
Corr(n) \;\; =\;\; SPD(n)/Diag_+(n)
$$

that arises from the group action $Diag_+(n)\times SPD(n) \to SPD(n)$ given by $(D,P) \to DPD$.  A natural projection $\pi: SPD(n) \to Corr(n)$ is given by the usual map that takes a covariance matrix to the corresponding correlation matrix by dividing the $ij$ term by $\sigma_i\sigma_j$.  Then in the special case $Corr(2)$, we see that ordinary matrix multiplication gives products that are elements of $SPD(2)$:

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & x \\
x & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & y \\
y & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 + xy & x+y \\
x+y & 1+xy \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

This can be used to define a product $C(x)*C(y) = \pi(C(x)C(y))$ where we find

$$
C(x)*C(y) \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & \frac{x+y}{1+xy} \\
\frac{x+y}{1+xy} & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

and $Corr(2)$ can be easily shown to be a commutative Lie group.  Although this is not technically a matrix Lie group (the product is not purely from matrix multiplication), the paper goes on to subsequently show that left-invariant vector fields are of the form

$$
S_x \;\; =\;\; s\left (1-x^2\right )
$$

and therefore the exponential map, defined for arbitrary Lie groups as the map Exp$(S) = \gamma_S(1)$ (maximal integral curve of the vector field $S$), gives rise to the ODE

$$
\dot{\gamma} \;\; =\;\; s\left (1-\gamma^2\right )
$$

which has the straightforward solution $\gamma(t) = \tanh(st)$.  Because $Corr(2)$ is essentially the interval $(-1,1)$ and $T_0Corr(2) = \mathbb{R}$, we find that $\tanh:\mathbb{R}\to Corr(2)$ is a bijective homomorphism with a smooth homomorphic inverse.